# Is it possible to set a colon (:) as a shortcut key in Xfce?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

On Xubuntu I'm trying to setup <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>**:** (colon)</kbd>
to do something.
I'm not sure it is possible.

I tried to add `/commands/custom/<Super>:` in Xubuntu's
`Settings Editor` → `xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts`
I also tried `/commands/custom/<Super>;`
Tried both combinations with a `<Shift>` to no avail.

Is there a way to do this or is this key un-bindable in Xfce?

Answer (score 0):

`/commands/custom/<Super>semicolon` did the trick